# Como reutilizar e compartilhar uma SSH private key entre Mac OS X e Linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, osx

Eu percebi que o [Mackup](https://github.com/lra/mackup/) é capaz de fazer backup da private key no Dropbox.
Tentei copiar minha antiga private key de um backup do Time Machine (fiz uma clean install do Mavericks), a qual estava sem senha, para minha home.

Quando tento usar a chave no OS X ele me pede uma senha como se a minha chave tivesse uma, e não me permite usa-la. Ainda não testei o que acontece no Linux.

Uso OS X 10.9.1 e Elementary OS Luna.

Comment: Minha solução foi criar uma nova chave seguindo a indicação do Emerson. Testei em uma máquina virtual rodando OS X 10.9 e ela aceitou a chave normalmente. Talvez o problema esteja relacionado a criação da chave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim como J Bruni disse, é uma questão de copiar a chave para o outro computador que quer usá-la.

Para o problema que citou sobre copiar a chave para outro Mac e ele pedir senha, recomendo que crie uma chave privada manualmente, como descrito em https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys e não adicione manualmente uma senha na hora que ele pedir para por senha. Se nem assim funcionar, crie a chave privada em um Linux ou Windows com Cywin e copie a chave gerada para todos os computadores.

Meu único receio quando a usar o Dropbox para permanecer com compartilhamento da chave privada é que ele pode ser comprometido. Lembre-se que chave privada é algo sério. Ela pode ser usada para fazer login sem senha, o que significa que se ela for exposta, isso pode causar muito estrago. Como não é algo que muda com frequência, é melhor ter ela em cada local.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer isso. Pra manter a segurança eu uso o login em duas etapas do Dropbox + senha de login em ambos sistemas.

Answer (score 0):

Copiar a chave privada no Dropbox facilita copiá-la para qualquer outro sistema onde queira usá-la.

No Linux, crie o diretório `~/.ssh`, caso não exista, e copie o arquivo da chave privada para o mesmo com o nome de `id_rsa`. Restrinja o acesso ao mesmo com um `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: Sempre que eu uso uma key gerada por outro Mac (por exemplo, aquela presente no meu backup) eu recebo essa mensagem: http://cl.ly/image/0G2X1z1d1z1w 
Sendo que, como eu disse, a chave não tinha sido criada com senha.

Comment: De acordo com [uma resposta no AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/26252), o Mac sempre pergunta por senha quando não encontra a chave pública correspondente (`id_rsa.pub` ou `id_dsa.pub`).

Comment: Não funcionou pra mim, talvez seja o método que eu usei para gerar ela que seja a causa do problema.